# How to enable XDebug in Apache but not in CLI?

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

I want to enable the XDebug module in PHP as run by Apache, but not for the CLI `php` command. I'm on Mac and I have Apache (httpd) and PHP 7.3 installed with Homebrew.

PHP runs much slower with XDebug enabled, even when I'm not debugging a given `php` command.

Comment: Hi, there is a separate php.ini configs for cli and for web server.

Comment: Just run php page where you show `phpinfo()` output. Do it via browser and you will see what config file (full path) was used. if you run the same script in CLI environment (terminal) you will see different config file path there.

Answer (score 7):

There are separate php.ini for CLI and Apache.
In `/etc/php/7.3/` there is an `apache2` and `cli` directory.
For enabling Xdebug in 'apache2/php.ini' add these lines:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1  
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

And for Xdebug's profiler:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
```

Comment: Welcome bro @dkellner